# Support Korean Font in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to use korean font in my Qt application, for that purpose I am using "JejuGothic" Font
and it works fine and for English language I am using "Luxi Sans".

Now the problem is onLoad I use "Luxi Sans" font for my English language display.
But when I change it to Korean from my combobox it displays blank thing.
When I change the font to JejuGothic on load it works fine.

But my requirement is I want to have "Luxi Sans" font for English and "JejuGothic" for Korean.
How can I do this?

Comment: How are you loading the font? Is it already installed on the platform independent of your app or are you loading it from a resources file/from a location deployed with your app? Also what platform are you on?

Comment: @sjwarner : I have multiple pages in my Application in each page i am using  QFont hfont("Luxi Sans", 10, QFont::Normal); and setting this font to all the controls. Iam in Linux env.

Comment: @sjwarner:It is installed on the platform.

Comment: Could you post some sample code? Which text encoding are you using? Also does your text mix the Luxi font and JejuGothic one?

Answer (score 1):

QFontInfo allows to identify, which font in actually used in case the font was not fount and loaded for some reason:

```
QFont font("NoFont", 10, QFont::Bold);
QFontInfo fontInfo(font);
qDebug() << "Expected:" <<  font.family() << "Real:" << fontInfo.family();

QFont font2("DejaVu Serif", 10, QFont::Bold);
QFontInfo fontInfo2(font2);
qDebug() << "Expected:" <<  font2.family() << "Real:" << fontInfo2.family();
```

Sample application output:

```
Expected: "NoFont" Real: "DejaVu Sans" 
Expected: "DejaVu Serif" Real: "DejaVu Serif"
```

As my system doesn't have font with family name "NoFont" it was substituted by "DejaVu Sans".